# MS Word tables object "not indexable" using COM in Python

Tags: python, ms-word, com, word-table

I am trying to autofit to contents for all the tables that are present in the word document using COM Interface. I face issue "The Tables object is not indexable". How to get the tables objects from the word document using python win32?

Code(Not Working):

```
def TableAutoFit():
    MsWord = Sys.OleObject["Word.Application"]  #using TestComplete and not win32com.Both use COM objects.
    if MsWord.ActiveDocument.Tables.Count > 0:
        MsWord.Browser.Target = 7
        for table in MsWord.ActiveDocument.Range().Tables:
            table.AutoFitBehavior(1)
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error? Does it make any difference if you use `MsWord.ActiveDocument.Content.Tables`

Comment: Hi Cindy Meister,

The For loop (Line 5) is causing the error. Yes we tried MsWord.ActiveDocument.Content.Tables but we get the error  "Tables is not indexable"